# WPF Combobox SelectedIndex Property Binding Not working

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I am trying to bind the SelectedIndex property of combobox to my ViewModel. Here is the code.

**Xaml:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="BloodGroupFilter" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedBloodGroupIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem Foreground="red" FontStyle="Italic">No Filter</ComboBoxItem>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource BloodGroupEnum}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

**ViewModel**

```
private int _selectedBloodGroupIndex = 4;
public int SelectedBloodGroupIndex {
    get { return _selectedBloodGroupIndex; }
    set { 
        _selectedBloodGroupIndex = value; 
    }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to set the SelectedIndex of combobox to "4". This doesn't happen and SelectedIndex is set to 0. Also, when user selects a particular item of the combobox, I was expecting that the ViewModel's SelectedBloodGroupIndex property will update itself to the currently selected item of combobox, but this doesn't happen either. The ViewModel property is never invoked(both set and get). Any reasons why binding is failing for the above code.

**Update**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="BloodGroupEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="enums:BloodGroup" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: How and where are you instantiating the ViewModel? Where do you bind it to the view?

Comment: I suspect you haven't set the `DataContext` properly. Does the Output window says about binding errors?

Comment: The ViewModel is created by the Caliburn Micro bootstrapper. The view too is created by Caliburn. I have some controls in View that are bound to ViewModel and these bindings are working fine. This suggests that the View is properly bound to the ViewModel. The only thing that doesn't work is setting the SelectedIndex of the Combobox as stated in my question

Comment: Could you also show us what the static data looks like?

Comment: I have updated the question to include StaticResource key definition.

Comment: Have to ask: Your ViewModel implements IPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes, though indirectly through Caliburn Conductor.

Answer (score 4):

You need to Notify Property changed in the setter of **SelectedBloodGroupIndex** of your ViewModel . I hope you do have the idea of PropertyChanged event.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:myWindow="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<Grid>
    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="2"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="3"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="4"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="5"/>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

```
 public partial class MainWindow :Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}

public class MyViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        SelectedIndex = 2;
    }
    private int _selectedIndex;
    public int SelectedIndex 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _selectedIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedIndex = value;
            Notify("SelectedIndex");
        }
  }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think PropertyChanged has anything to do in the current scenario. Nevertheless, I added the code in the setter of SelectedBloodGroupIndex, but it doesn't do any good. The problem is that the Setter/Getter is not being invoked at any time in the setup.

Comment: I have updated solution with example. If its not working like this then the problem is in your Binding.

Comment: Good catch, but `INotifyPropertyChanged` is helpful when you update your View from the ViewModel only. OP has problems with updating ViewModel from View, and the getter and setter don't even get called.